# saving the data that is passed through intents

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have a TextView and a Button in my first activity and an EditText and a Button in my second Activity.when i click a button in my first activity it must be redirected to second Activity.In the second activity i want to give the data in the EditText and click the button it must be redirected to first activity and second Activity EditText value must be displayed in the TextView given in the first activity.my problem is i want to save the EditText data after returning back from the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

 private void gotoActivityB(){
   startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),101);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == 101 {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String value = data.getStringExtra("KEY");
     }
 }

 }
}



public class ActivityB extends Activity {
      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra("KEY",editTextValue);
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: use Intent  transfer data

Comment: i am unable to move from second activity to first activity

Comment: 1.in first activity use startActivityForResult open second activity. 2.in second activity's onDestroy or onStop set setResult. 3.then first activity onActivityResult will receive the data